# Python Plotly Scatter Plot on 3D Mesh

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, scatter-plot, mesh

I have an STL(mesh) file that I want to render on plotly. I found [this](https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/) library which is using

> import plotly.graph_objects as go

the go object of plotly.
and I want to make a scatter plot on the same graph and not sure how to do that.
At the end the problem is using the plotly graph_object with ploty express object together (at least this is the solution that I think can be done. ) If you know how to render a mesh and render some points on it it would be great.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the traces to a single Figure.

For example:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

pts = np.loadtxt(np.DataSource().open('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/mesh_dataset.txt'))
x, y, z = pts.T

mesh = go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, color='lightpink', opacity=0.50)
scatter = go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers')

fig = go.Figure(data=[mesh, scatter])

fig.show()
```

[image]